# Minitoc Entry Font

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I am trying to make a minitoc, but the whole document is in an unusual font (specifically [This one](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/janaskrivana/) if it matters). I have managed to get everything else right, but the entries of the `\minitoc` are in the wrong font, as shown in an example below, except the page numbers themselves, which are correct.

[image: exmaple of minitoc produced]

I have tried the font commands listed in the documentation, as `\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\Fontskrivan}`. With a bunch of trial and error, I have managed to get the page numbers in the right font, but not the actual entries.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in,bindingoffset=0in, footskip=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc,tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{50}{55}\selectfont}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\dominitoc% Initialization
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\Fontskrivan}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\fontsize{50}{55}\selectfont\Fontskrivan Table of Contents}
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\begin{document}
\Fontskrivan
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Tester}
\minitoc
\newpage
\section{Stuff}

\newpage
\section{Stuff 2}

\newpage
\chapter{Terster 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The log shows that some sizes (e.g., 50) are not available, and size substitutions are being done; and also that sometimes scaling is being done; plus sometimes default font substitution is being done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amended answer:

Luckily, JanaSkrivana font has `.tfm` files defined. And a reverse slant.

So, using `fontspec`, we can set up all the faces, with "regular" slant occupying the italics command, and the reverse slant sitting in the slant command (say):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = * ,
    BoldFont = *Bold ,
    ItalicFont = *Slant ,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldSlant ,
    SlantedFont = *Rslant ,
    BoldSlantedFont = *BoldRslant , 
]{JanaSkrivana}
```

[image: JanaSkrivana sample]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = * ,
    BoldFont = *Bold ,
    ItalicFont = *Slant ,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldSlant ,
    SlantedFont = *Rslant ,
    BoldSlantedFont = *BoldRslant , 
]{JanaSkrivana}

%%\newfontfamily\fontjs{JanaSkrivana}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in,bindingoffset=0in, footskip=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc,tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\dominitoc% Initialization
%\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\fontjs}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\fontsize{50}{55}\selectfont Table of Contents}

\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\newcommand\testtext{{\large abc qwerty}}

\begin{document}
upright text \textbf{bold face weight} \textit{italic shape} \textbf{\textit{bold italic}}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!12}
Font & Command & Result & Comment \\
upright & 
-- & 
\testtext &
regular\\
bold & 
textbf & 
\textbf{\testtext}  &
bold\\
slanted & 
textit & 
\textit{\testtext}  &
slanted further\\
boldslanted & 
textbf, textit & 
\textbf{\textit{\testtext}}  &
slanted further, bold\\
rslanted & 
textsl & 
\textsl{\testtext}  &
slanted other way\\
boldrslanted & 
textbf, textsl & 
\textbf{\textsl{\testtext}}  &
slanted other way, bold\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Tester}
\minitoc
\testtext
\newpage
\section{Stuff\fontname\font}

\newpage
\section{Stuff 2}

\newpage
\chapter{Terster 2}
\end{document}
```

---

*Original answer*

Not an answer because not entirely clear on what you want (e.g., the large font size in the header).

If I use fontspec, set the main font to JanaSkivana, and compile with lualatex, everything is in that font, `\fontskrivan` is not needed (nor the `aurical` package, etc), nor the mtc renewcommand, and so on.

[image: JanaSkrivana]

I put a `\fontname\font` in to check the font being used.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{JanaSkrivana}
\newfontfamily\fontjs{JanaSkrivana}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in,bindingoffset=0in, footskip=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc,tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\dominitoc% Initialization
%\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\fontjs}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\fontsize{50}{55}\selectfont Table of Contents}

\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Tester}
\minitoc
\newpage
\section{Stuff\fontname\font}

\newpage
\section{Stuff 2}

\newpage
\chapter{Terster 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I wanted the sizes I had, but all in the same font. This seems to do it, so I am good with it.

Comment: I was doing proofreading, and noticed that this method doesn't allow for bolding or italicising (in either `\textbf` or `\bfseries` version), even though the forms exist in the documentation for the font. I didn't include body text because I didn't think it would be relevant, but it is, at least in the bolding part

Comment: Do you want a `fontspec` solution, or a legacy font solution? (or both?) The sizes will still be substituted, though, depending on combinations of things. Note also: JanaSkrivana has regular, bold, slanted, boldslanted; no italic (fair enough for a handwriting font - see the doc). I'll try `fontspec` first.

Comment: See amended answer. `fontspec` allows options at the typeface level (and even more low-level granularity if needed (e.g., for specific size ranges, or if smallcaps were involved, etc)).